# External IP redirects to router landing page

Tags: networking, router

When I type my external IP I get redirected to the router landing page, is this safe? Do I need to disable this? and if so how do I do it?

I'm also a bit worried since the router displays a lot of information without the need of logging in, How can I disable this?

I have tried redirecting port 80 to an IP that doesn't exist  `0.0.0.0`  but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your router should have the option to turn off administration or access from the WAN. But since you've given us no information about what router you're using it's hard to say how.

Comment: @NelsonHoover I'm using the `Vtech NB403` using a custom ISP firmware. Also how do you usually disable this setting?

Answer (score 0):

With custom ISP firmware, it's anyone's guess. There doesn't seem to be much info out there that I could find about this router, but it should be similar to other routers.

For example, in a DLink, you would go to the Tools tab, select the Admin section and select Remote Management to enable/disable it.

I saw your router should have a section called Tools. I would examine the options under that section for something similar.